# How to negative lookbehind for special characters

Tags: r, regex

I want to

1. exclude any sentence that has No or no in it unless the No is followed by a colon or a question mark
2. Then I want to get rid of any sentence containing a question mark or a colon followed by a N or No or no.

***Input text:***

```
N-Acetyl-cysteine used Yes or no?No.
Acetic acid used Yes or no?Y.
NBI used Yes or no? Y.
Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
: Y -33cm.
Inlet patch - Yes or No: N.
No loss of stain.
```

***Desired output***

```
Acetic acid used Yes or no?Y.
NBI used Yes or no? Y.
Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
: Y -33cm.
```

***Current attempt in r:***

```
gsub(".*[Nn][Oo](?![:]|[?]).*?(\\.|\n|:|$)", "", x[, y], perl = T)
```

results in:

```
    N-Acetyl-cysteine used Yes or no?No.
    Acetic acid used Yes or no?Y.
    NBI used Yes or no? Y.
    Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
    : Y -33cm.
    Inlet patch - Yes or No: N.
```

then

```
gsub(".*[Nn][Oo](:|\\?)(\\s*).*?(\\.|\n|:|$)", "", x[, y])
```

results in:

```
Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
: Y -33cm.
```

The first gsub works fine but the second doesn't gets rid of too much. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: [Is this what you need?](https://ideone.com/SGF2LT)

Comment: Your second answer works like a charm. Please post as an answer. If you could explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second requirement should include optional whitespace between the colon or question mark and `N`.

The regex must look like

```
.*(?:no(?![?:])|[?:]\s*N).*\R*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tozha8/1)

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:no(?![?:])|[?:]\s*N)` - a non-capturing alternation group matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `no(?![?:])` - `no` not followed with `?` or `:`
  - `|` - or
  - `[?:]\s*N` - a `?` or `:`, 0+ whitespaces, `N`
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R*` - any 0+ line break sequences.

The `perl=TRUE` argument makes R parse the pattern with the PCRE regex engine, and `ignore.case=TRUE` argument makes the pattern case insensitive.

Here is the [fixed R code](https://ideone.com/SGF2LT):

```
x <- "N-Acetyl-cysteine used Yes or no?No.
Acetic acid used Yes or no?Y.
NBI used Yes or no? Y.
Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
: Y -33cm.
Inlet patch - Yes or No: N.
No loss of stain."
cat(gsub(".*(?:no(?![?:])|[?:]\\s*N).*\\R*", "", x, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Acetic acid used Yes or no?Y.
NBI used Yes or no? Y.
Diaphragmatic pinch:40cm
: Y -33cm.
```

Comment: I've just noticed that the regex also picks up phrases like "A large mass was noticed" presumably because it captures every "no" that isn't followed by a "?" or ":" whereas I would also like it to not detect phrases where "no" is part of a word...how to do? I've tried .*(?:no(?![?:]|[A-Za-z])|[?:]\\s*N).* but no success

Comment: Use word boundaries, `.*(?:\\bno\\b(?![?:])|[?:]\\s*N).*\\R*`, or, to also enforce it for the second alternative, `.*(?:\\bno\\b(?![?:])|[?:]\\s*No?\\b).*\\R*`.